# How do I select the the grand-children DOMs with the same class (SaSS)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass

```
<li className={styles.option}>
   <div>Hi
      <ul>
      <li className={styles.option}> /*** I want these two li DOMs as 'blue'
         <div>Hi
            <ul>
            <li className={styles.option}>   
               <div>Hi</div>
            </li>
            </ul>
         </div>
         
      </li>*****************************************/
    </div>
    </ul>
</li>
```

I tried many ways but it didn't work

```
.option {
  background-color: 'yellow'

  &:has(.option) {
    background-color: 'blue'
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would make the first li with the option class blue, and the second one yellow:

```
.option {
  background-color: blue;

  .option {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work on my end... weird... I tried it several times

Comment: That's weird indeed. Normally It would make the second one yellow. Maybe you could provide the fully nested snippet?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this without changing the option class on your parent `<li>` you can use the solution below.

```css
li:nth-child(2) {
  background: blue;
}

li:nth-child(3) {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<li>
   <div>Outside
      <li class="option">
         <div>Middle
            <li class="option">   
               <div>Inside</div>
            </li>
         </div>
      </li>
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: I have over 10 nested "option" classes. Thanks for providing the example though. I've up-voted